# Why still use Frequentist Methods?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, frequentist

It is possible to do hypothesis testing, regression, classification, ect, all using Bayesian methods. Furthermore, these Bayesian methods are more flexible and easily interpret-able than Frequentist methods. Therefore, why solve a statistical problem in a more difficult manner? Really, the true reason why frequentist methods were standard is issues of computing. With lack of computer the Bayesian approach was not feasible. Now it is no longer an issue. Therefore, why would anyone still rely on frequenstist methods? Furthermore, still universities still teach frequenstist methods, or entirely abandon them? Look at it this way, the slide-ruler was once taught in universities, now nobody teaches it anymore since there is a better alternative. So why continue to use, and to teach frequentist statistics?

The only reason that I can think of is that frequentist methods are computationally faster (substantially) than Bayesian methods. For example, it is possible to do simple linear regression with least squares with thousands of predictor variables and a dataset in the trillions, very quickly, but that task might be too long to calculate for MCMC.

**Edit:** It says "question closed" because "it is not focused". This objection to close the question is non-sense, there is only one question being asked, namely, "why would anyone use a frequentist approach when it can be solved in a Bayesian manner?".

Comment: Not all scholars, e.g. Fisher, embrace the subjectivist view of probability.

Comment: @utobi That is an "academic" objection. In practice, the answers are usually the same. One can replace any frequentist answer, by a Bayesian calculation which produces that same answer, and then interpret it the frequentist way.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/194152/76981

Comment: @Nicolas Bourbaki I'm confused by your comments. If it were true that a prior exists that generates the same numerical value as a frequentist analysis, but that Bayesian analysis is more computationally burdensome then why do Bayesians bother with the Bayesian approach?

Comment: @CliffAB Thank you Dr. Cliff . The reason cited as #1, seems to be computational speed, at the end of the day, in most cases.

Comment: @GrahamBornholt Because complex models are difficult to fit using a frequenstist method. The Bayesian approach is intuitive and straightforward in many cases.

Comment: Why do you say frequentist methods, such as MLE, are more difficult than MCMC? MCMC works for everything _in theory_, but in practice is very finicky and often is too slow to move through the posterior space.

Comment: @CliffAB Let us say, for example, you want linear regression which minimizes the total squared error. That is easy to do. Now let us suppose you want to linear regression which minimizes the total absolute error. Suddenly, that is no longer solvable with least squares, so you will have to switch to the simplex algorithm to locate the MLE. However, in the Bayesian approach you would do least-squares by using a normal residual, and absolute-minimum-deviation by using an exponential residual. Notice that the Bayesian solution is almost the same and only changes in the residual distribution.

Comment: There are two topics being discussed: the model and the algorithm. The model is no simpler in a Bayesian approach than a frequentist as the likelihood is identical. So I think your claim is that MCMC can be applied to any model. While this is technically true (i.e. even a naive MH will cover the posterior *eventually*), in is not practically true due to how poorly MCMC methods cover posteriors that are oddly shaped (i.e. complex models). In my experience, *more* researcher time is spent specializing algorithms to models in Bayesian methods than Frequentists, although I will admit it can vary.

Comment: @CliffAB You are the only one in this question discussion who actually gave a meaningful answer. Everyone else's answer is just an academic response (e.g. "because there is no prior") which does not actually answer the question in practice.

Comment: There are a lot of vested interests involved. Many practitioners would have to admit "I've used flawed methods in the last 5–30 years". Very few people are capable of such honesty.

Comment: @pglpm Which frequentist methods are flawed? I think you will struggle to name any. Problems only arise when used by the untrained or unskilled. Any tool can be misused ("don't give a scapel to a child")

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki Having read your responses here and to the two answers, I see that you practice in a very privileged setting with such large amounts of data that the choice of prior "washes out". Most statisticians don't have this luxury (see the vast majority of scientific research, for example). If we were to accept your standard then scientific progress would be drastically slowed. Frequentists are interested in modelling the data-generating process itself, rather than model their own   personal uncertainty: it's not about computing power.

Comment: @GrahamBornholt So I take it that if you roll a brand-new die once and you get a "five", you let the data-generating process speak for itself and deduce that the die will give "five" at every future roll. You don't? it's because you're using a prior. Frequentists methods don't avoid priors, they just hide them from view. They involve personal choices at every step: from which of the 1001 formulae to use, to which threshold use for p-values.

Comment: @GrahamBornholt Logical and mathematical proofs of how frequentist methods are intrinsically flawed (that is, when *correctly* used) have been appearing since 1935. Examples: <https://doi.org/10.1017/S030500410001330X> <https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1961.10482103> <https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1962.10480661> <https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-010-1436-6_6> <https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1987.10478397> <https://www.jstor.org/stable/27855070> <https://www.inference.org.uk/itila/book.html> §37.3. I have studied and checked them. No "frequentist" colleague I know has.

Comment: @pglpm Thanks for the list of articles you claim show "logical and mathematical proofs" that frequentist methods are flawed. I only know two of these papers well, and neither show that frequentist methods are flawed.
   
Savage's discussion is about Birnbaum's proof of the Likelihood Principle from the Sufficiency and Conditionality Principles, calling the event 'historic'. That was very premature, since Birnbaum shortly after publication rejected both his own version of the Conditionality Principle and the Likelihood Principle. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_principle

Comment: @GrahamBornholt I claim they show logical and mathematical proofs. You *claim*, as well, that two of them don't. A big general problem today is that everything, at the end, is just a "claim". Science has been dead quite a long time :(

Comment: Regarding the 1987 Berger and Sellke paper, there is nothing troubling for frequentists in that paper. Once the test statistic is selected for a test, the resulting p-value can be regarded as a measure of the (statistical) consistency of the data with the null hypothesis, irrespective of any alternative hypothesis that may or may not have been proposed. As I pointed out in my letter published in JASA at the time in response (1987, no. 400, p.1201), p-values are measures of absolute plausibility but not relative plausibility. ...

Comment: In essence, Berger and Sellke simply confirmed that p-values are not suitable as measures of relative plausibility. No surprises there.

Answer (score 1):

Frequentist approaches make sense in the context of randomized control trials (RCTs).

In an RCT, an "exposure" is randomly assigned to a patient.  If the exposure were nothing more than a placebo (i.e. we were just randomizing for the sake of randomizing) then the null hypothesis literally would be true.

So knowing that (and making some assumptions about the sampling distribution of the test statistic), frequentist statistics make a lot of sense.  You can say "had the exposure had no effect, then the probability I would see results at least as extreme as what I saw is...".  Of course, you have to make modelling and distributional assumptions when you make this statement.  Bayesian methods are not immune to this.

Additionally, it isn't like the analysis of RCTs is a uniquely frequentist thing.  Bayesian methods can be used for that too.  But Frequentist methods can bound things like the false positive rate and the false negative rate (conditional on aforementioned assumptions, which I will repeat must be made in the Bayesian framework too).

Being able to control these error rates is very valuable in medicine and drug discovery.  You're (ostensibly) able to ensure that 20% of all interventions which do have an effect fail to be discovered (or whatever your false negative rate is) $^\star$.

Bayesian's don't care about false positive/negative rates.  And I think there is your answer: We still use frequentist methods when care about those error rates.  If you care about those rates or not (or should care about them) is orthogonal in my opinion.  IF you care about them, frequentism is a good tool.

$^\star$ Little bit of nuance here.  Its 20% of all interventions which have the assumed minimal detectable effect.  Here we see a really important point against frequentism; it isn't very intuitive and is filled with overloaded words like "confidence".  I feel this is a more damning objection to the framework.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this answer. It is possible to get a p-value using a Bayesian method. I can run a t-test, get a p-value, and solve the same problem the Bayesian way, and instead get the probability that one mean is larger than another mean. I can then interpret that result as the "false-positive". If the answer that is obtained is the same as the frequenstist method, one can then give that answer the same interpretation.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki you could obtain a P value from a Bayesian method, but their calibration would be questionable due to the ability to specify a prior. If you use a non- informative prior in what sense are you really leveraging Bayesian methods? To be clear, I am a Bayesian myself. I’m just trying to argue from the other side.

Answer (score 1):

It’s familiar, so customers, bosses, and reviewers might be less likely to think you’re trying to “pull a fast one” on them.

It’s easy to implement.

There are no prior distributions for people to criticize.

The results returned from frequentist and Bayesian methods often (though certainly not always) lead to the same actions (e.g., “yes, we should use the new drug”).

Comment: "There are no prior distributions for people to criticize." In my experience, by running simulations with few variables, it does not matter what the prior distribution even is, as long as it is not something pathological, and you have enough data. Indeed, just consider Bernoulli(p) estimation with a horrendous prior, but if you have enough data, the prior does not matter anymore. Therefore, the criticism of the prior distribution is academic, in practice, it seems to not even matter.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki That assumes you have enough data to overwhelm a bad prior. Not every field has large amounts of data.

Comment: Once one says "the prior doesn't matter because the likelihood overwhelms it", then one might was well also say "Bayesian methods don't matter, because their results just approach those of MLE's".

Comment: @Dave If a problem (in science let us say) has a limited amount of data, then the conclusions that one draws from that are questionable. Indeed, there is a replication crisis. Part of the reason why there is this replication crisis is that people have small amounts of data in order to get favorable p-values. If one objects to Bayesian methods because "I have small amount of data", then one might have more serious problems in replication.

Comment: @CliffAB Yes, you can just replace it by MLEs. However, how would one calculate an MLE for a complex model? Bayesian calculation runs on Markov chains which makes it possible to do those calculations. Hence, in general, the Bayesian approach would be superior because it allows one to work with many more models and is a lot more flexible.

Comment: @Dave That is not an argument. My point was that if you are doing frequentist analysis with 9 data points, then that is just suspicious altogether. Responding back with a comment like that completely fails to address my question.